# Is there a standard as to how many meters or feet if a GPS number (latitude and longitude) is off by a tiny amount, such as 0.0001?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

For example, if the latitude and longitude is

```
25.1054, 121.5973
```

then what if it is off by a small amount, such as `0.0001`:

```
25.1055, 121.5974
```

Then can it readily tell how many feet or meters it is off by?

Comment: Not directly because lengths in degrees vs. meters vary. You will find loads of reading by searching "great circle distance" and "haversine formula".

Comment: it is not `0.0001` translating to about 11.1 meters as in the answers of the other question?

Comment: If you are at latitude of 70 degrees you can check with this calculator http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html that in East-West direction it translates to about 3.8 meters.